# Is there any better way to get a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python

Is there any better way to get a list of numbers, such as:

```
with open('number.txt','w+') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            for l in range(10):
                for m in range(10):
                    f.write('189'+str(i)+str(j)+str(l)+str(m)+'8888\n')
```

Comment: What would be the reason to save this numbers and not the start and end number instead?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(1890000, 1899999+1):
  f.write('{}8888\n'.format(i))
```

**Edit 2:** updated, thanks @Selcuk for pointing out the error.

Comment: This will print numbers such as `18900008889`, which is not in the expected output.

Comment: @Selcuk you are correct, thanks for pointing it out, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use basic [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
for i in range(10**4):
    f.write('189{:04d}8888\n'.format(i))
```

The `{:04d}` placeholder will pad numbers to to four digits with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` for a more general solution:

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=4):
    f.write('189{0}{1}{2}{3}8888\n'.format(*item))
```

Comment: @MSeifert You are right, fixed now! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

There were some updates, so here is a new set of timing runs.  After the changes, they all seem to be roughly the same, with the itertools option being a bit slower.

```
import itertools

def option_range1():
    f = open('output1.txt', 'w+')
    for i in range(1890000, 1899999+1):
        f.write('{}8888\n'.format(i))
    f.close()

def option_iter():
    f = open('output2.txt', 'w')
    for item in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=4):
        f.write('189{0}{1}{2}{3}8888\n'.format(*item))
    f.close()

def option_range2():
    with open('output3.txt','w+') as f:
        for i in range(10**4):
            f.write('189{:04d}8888\n'.format(i))

%timeit -n 1000 option_range1()
1000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop

%timeit -n 1000 option_range2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop

%timeit -n 1000 option_iter()
1000 loops, best of 3: 18 ms per loop
```

Comment: First option is incorrect, I updated my answer.